# What is the difference between swap entries in fstab?

Tags: linux, swap

I've been looking around and seen two different things ways to declare swap in fstab.

I've seen something like the line below:

```
UUID=UUID-HERE none swap sw 0 0
```

and

```
UUID=UUID-HERE none swap swap 0 0`
```

What, if anything, is the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the filesystem type is `swap`, *neither* of these options mean anything. In fact, the only option that makes sense is `pri=n`, specifying the swap space priority. Usually you don't need it and can just specify `defaults`:

```
UUID=foo   none   swap   defaults
```

(The mount point, as well as dump and pass fields, are irrelevant too.)

Comment: Thanks, I figured mount dump and pass were irrelevant. I hadn't seen it as defaults before, but I have since I was searching after asking the question.