# What does "sw" option mean in /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, fstab, man

In my Ubuntu 14.04 */etc/fstab*, I have following line:

```
UUID=e4YGg1-2bHU-Ylum-3FwK-MK3s-1Fjf-ZvQEh2 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Which seems pretty current for swap.

I can't figure out what the **sw** option stand for. There is no indication in fstab man neither swapon's.

Any idea?

Comment: I think [this](http://superuser.com/questions/337410/what-is-the-difference-between-swap-entries-in-fstab) may tell you what you want to know: it confirms what I always assumed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the link below, the 'sw' option indicates that the swap partition is to be activated with 'swapon -a' command:

```
/dev/hda6 none swap sw 0 0
```

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/fstab-defaults-sets-wrong-permissions-145958/

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html: `-a, --all: All devices marked as ``swap'' in /etc/fstab are made available, except for those with the ``noauto'' option.` Also: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/sys-utils/swapon.c?h=v2.27.1#n677

Comment: Same case for the version Ubuntu 14.04 has: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/mount/swapon.c?h=v2.20.1#n611

Answer (score 4):

This column is described in Linux's [`man fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) as:

> The fourth field, (`fs_mntops`), describes the mount options associated with the filesystem.
>
> It is formatted as a comma separated list of options. It contains at least the type of mount plus any additional options appropriate to the filesystem type. For documentation on the available options for non-nfs file systems, see `mount(8)`.

When the file system is `swap`, these mount options don't do anything. See: [What is the difference between swap entries in fstab?](https://superuser.com/a/337465/87805)

These fstab options are part of `struct fstab`:

```
 struct fstab {
         char    *fs_spec;       /* block special device name */
         char    *fs_file;       /* filesystem path prefix */
         char    *fs_vfstype;    /* type of filesystem */
         char    *fs_mntops;     /* comma separated mount options */
         char    *fs_type;       /* rw, ro, sw, or xx */
         int     fs_freq;        /* dump frequency, in days */
         int     fs_passno;      /* pass number on parallel fsck */
 };
```

So in summary there are 6 columns in `/etc/fstab` means:

1. `fs_spec`: describes the block special device, the local filesystem, or the remote filesystem to be mounted.
2. `fs_file`: describes the mount point for the filesystem.  For swap partitions, this field should be specified as `none`.
3. `fs_vfstype`: describes the type of the filesystem.
4. **`fs_mntops`: describes the mount options associated with the filesystem.**
5. `fs_freq`: is used for these filesystems by the `dump` command to determine which filesystems need to be dumped.
6. `fs_passno`: is used by the `fsck` program to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at reboot time.

Comment: Well, `ro` and `rw` are documented in mount(8): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html, while `sw` and `xx` probably make no sense in Linux. Also, fstab in Linux has only 6 fields, `ro` and `rw` belongs to the mount options field.

Comment: That's correct, 4th column describes the mount options associated with the filesystem.

Comment: Clarified further more.

Comment: Hm actually my point is, it's a bit pointless to bring up the BSD fstab for the question. fstab in Linux has 6 fields, while according to the code you quoted, fstab in BSD has 7. And the extra one that BSD has while Linux doesn't is `char    *fs_type;       /* rw, ro, sw, or xx */`. I mean, yeah BSD has it, but so? It's a bit like saying "both `sw` and `swap` starts with `sw`, so `sw` means `swap`".

Comment: @Tom Corrected the inconsistency issues.